# How to layout Grids inside a row in flutter with divider

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a three boxes max inside a Row, each having an aspect ratio of 1/1.

I tried to nest a GridView but I am getting back an error
`The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.`

I used the `Row` and `Expanded(flex: 1)` to get the desired output but since I am not always going to render 3 boxes I am unable to keep the aspect ratio of the children ( like if its 2 boxes just draw the same main container with 1 box missing).

This looks like some thing like this

[image]

```
Container(
  child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        ConstrainedBox(
          child: ...
        ),

        Expanded(

            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7,bottom: 7, left: 7, right: 0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                
                    _buildProductsCard(3),
                    _buildProductsCard(3),
                  ],
                )
            )
        ),
        
      ],
    )
)
```

the `_buildProductsCard` Where I tried the GridView

```
  Widget _buildProductsCard(int n) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      color: lightGreyColor,
      // height: 120,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 3,
        child: 
        // GridView(
        //   // shrinkWrap: true,
        //   crossAxisCount: 3,
        //   children: _buildProductImages(n),
        // )
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: _buildProductImages(n)

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

the `_buildProductImages`

```
  List<Widget> _buildProductImages(int num) {
    List<Widget> images = [];
    for(var i= 0; i <num; i++) {
      images.add(_buildImageBox());
      if(i<2) {
        images.add(SizedBox(width: 2,));
      }
    }
    return images;
  }

  Widget _buildImageBox() {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: cannot you build always 3 boxes (possibly "empty" at the end, using just `SizedBox`)?

Comment: without an answer that is what I am going to do, Its just its going to be a long list. I was just trying to avoid drawing widgets that I dont need If that make sense @pskink

Comment: you will have max (2 * number of visible rows) empty widgets - assuming the case where each row has only one "valid" box - how many visible rows do you have? i guess it is 10-15 max, so...

Comment: there is only one row, I made two to discribe tthe effect I wanted. One row with max items(boxes) of 3 (but can be also 1 or 2) @pskink

Comment: so what is the problem if you have 2 extra "empty" widgets? typical flutter app uses hundreds of them... ;-)